# Assign a value to a sql field in Joomla

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I have a SQL field defined in Joomla XML as follows

```
name="atypeandmeasureunit" type="sql" default="10" 
onchange="showhideFields()"
query="SELECT concat(measureunit, atype) as atype, atype AS atype2 FROM   
#__tablename" key_field="atype" value_field="atype2" required="true"
```

which works fine but i also need under condition, to write code to assign a value to the sql field (which of course will exist as a record in the sql field values).

The code below does nothing.

```
$this->form->setValue('atypeandmeasureunit', null, $measureunit-
>value||$atype->value);
```

Can you please help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to update the sql from your model and adding extra row to it from here

```
  $form->setFieldAttribute('atypeandmeasureunit', 'query', 'SELECT concat(measureunit, atype) as atype, atype AS atype2 FROM   
#__tablename UNION SELECT  "add_type" AS atype, "add_type_2" AS atype2 ');
```

also you can use a custom filed type that extended from JFormFieldSQL and override the getOptions method